# Turning images in game

Tags: java, image, swing

For a school project I am making a tron game and I am currently using pictures for the bikes. The bikes move across the screen so as of now we are using 4 different pictures so that if a key is clicked to turn the bike, then the bike displays a new image at that point. Right now I am just trying to find the best way to display the image and turn it when a key is clicked. Would it be better to have 4 different images or rotate the image. Please help with either situation.

```
public class contents extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener
{

    private int x = 0, y = 0;
    private Timer t;
    private ImageIcon d1 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("BlueBike.jpg"));
    private Image bike1 = d1.getImage();; 
    private ImageIcon d2 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("BlueBike2.jpg"));
    private Image bike2 = d2.getImage();; 
    private ImageIcon d3 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("BlueBike3.jpg"));
    private Image bike3 = d3.getImage();; 
    private ImageIcon d4 = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("BlueBike4.jpg"));
    private Image bike4 = d4.getImage();; 
    private char direction = 'd';
    private char newdirection = 'd';
    public contents() 

    {
        super.setDoubleBuffered(true);
        t = new Timer(7, this);
        t.start();

    }


    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D)g;

        if (direction == 'r')
        g2D.drawImage(bike1, x, y, this);
        if (direction == 'l')
            g2D.drawImage(bike2, x, y, this);
        if (direction == 'u')
            g2D.drawImage(bike3, x, y, this);
        if (direction == 'd')
            g2D.drawImage(bike4, x, y, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        //x=x+1;

        direction = newdirection;
        repaint();

    }



    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        int  code = e.getKeyCode();
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {
            newdirection = 'r';
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        {
            newdirection = 'l';
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        {
            newdirection = 'u';
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        {
            newdirection = 'd';
        }

    }


    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }



    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

Comment: Store four different images, but you can create three images from a single image that you've read in by creating a new BufferedImage, drawing the existing image into it using a Graphics2D object obtained from the BufferedImage, and rotating and translating your image using AffineTransform. You will want to search on this to learn how to use it first.

Comment: I tried using affine transformations but I am moving the image across the screen using a timer and when I use AffineTransform the image does not continue moving

Comment: Please don't confuse two very different issues here: 1) creating and storing rotated or flipped images -- use AffineTransforms for this, and 2) translating an image across the screen -- you *may* use AffineTransforms for this, but likely you won't.

Comment: If your images above already are rotations of your bike, then skip the affine transformation business completely, and instead simply store your images. Myself, I'd create an enum to represent Direction, and I'd store my images in a Map, that maps each Direction item with an image of my sprite that is going in that direction. Then the paintComponent code would replace the if block with something like: `g2D.drawImage(bikeImageMap.get(direction), bikeX, bikeY, this);`

Comment: I am still a beginner and that is very confusing. Would you be able to explain a little more?? Thank you so much for your help by the way

Answer (score -1):

Ideally, you would have an image [Sprite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_%28computer_graphics%29) with all of the images your game will need. If, for whatever reason, you cannot generate a [Sprite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_%28computer_graphics%29) you are better off with creating 4 different images than rotating the image. You can figure out why on your own, it's pretty simple.